# why am i getting a sql query when i try to get a property of an entity?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-query-syntax

I am trying to get the value of properties of this entity (this entity is inside the list "trabajadores"), but I ended up getting a "sql query" in "CodCar" property  when it is supposed to give me a value. It doesn't happen with other properties of the same object.
It happens with all elements of this list.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it by adding the dataset again and recompiling.